# Import WSDL file into Javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, wsdl

I want to import a WSDL in XML file to my JavaScript project, which will allow my to use web client to search info.

Is there any special way to import it into my project, or do I need a package, or need to convert it into JS? I know there is a soap package in NPM, but I hope it's not the only way to do that. I've also read tutorials on W3 and still not quite sure how to manage that.

I've got something like this:

```
    function soap() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', '127.0.0.1/start.html', true);

        // build SOAP request
        var sr =
                '<soapenv:Envelope ' +
                    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
                    'xmlns:aut="http://demo.krd.pl/Authorization" xmlns:dto="http://demo.krd.pl/Chase3.1/Dto"> ' +
                    '<soapenv:Header> ' + 
                        '<aut:Authorization> '+
                            '<aut:AuthorizationType>LoginAndPassword</aut:AuthorizationType> ' +
                            '<aut:Login>login</aut:Login> ' +
                            '<aut:Password>password</aut:Password> ' +
                        '</aut:Authorization> ' +
                    '</soapenv:Header> ' +
                    '<soapenv:Body> ' +
                        '<dto:SearchNonConsumerRequest> ' +
                            '<dto:Number>24041803749</dto:Number> ' +
                            '<dto:NumberType>TaxId</dto:NumberType> ' +
                        '</dto:SearchNonConsumerRequest> ' +
                    '</soapenv:Body> ' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope> ';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
        // send request
        // ...
    }
```

Also, where the response will be saved or will it just be posted in console?

Comment: Please include a basic simple example of the project file that needs the WSDL file!

Comment: i hope, that's what you meant. Just added the code. I got something like this from the documentation, but they changed something and it doesnt work, cause they changed it to WSDL i guess.